# Java Chess: Method to check if player in check not working properly

Tags: java

Here's my rough setup for a chess game written in Java.  There are four main objects:

Board: 2d array (8 x 8) of Square objects
Square: has a color, integer height, integer width, and piece object
Piece: all types of pieces inherit from this (e.g. Rook, Bishop, etc.)
Player: for now just has a color field (which pieces are theirs)

I'm trying to write a method in my Board class that will check whether a given player is in check (given the current state of the board).

Here's my attempt:

```
public boolean isInCheck(Player candidatePlayer) {

    String candidateColor = candidatePlayer.getColor();

    //get opposite color of candidatePlayer
    String oppositeColor = candidateColor.equals("w") ? "b" : "w";

    //loop through squares
    for (int i = 0; i < myBoard.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myBoard[i].length; j++) {
            //if current square not empty
            if (! myBoard[i][j].isEmpty()) {
                //if piece at current square is opposite color of candidate player
                if (! myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getColor().equals(oppositeColor)) {
                    //if piece's current legal squares moves contains square of candidatePlayer's king
                    if (candidateColor.equals("w")) {
                        if (myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getLegalDestinationSquares(myBoard[i][j]).contains(whiteKingSquare)) {
                                return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getLegalDestinationSquares(myBoard[i][j]).contains(blackKingSquare)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've set up my board so that there is no pawn in front of the black King (coordinates [1][4] are null) and there is a white Queen on e2 (coordinates [6][4]).

Any idea why this might be returning false?  I'm pretty sure my "getLegalDestinationSquares" method has been written correctly (but happy to post that if you think it might be the issue).

Thanks!

Comment: `I'm pretty sure my "getLegalDestinationSquares" method has been written correctly ` - pretty big claim! What does your debugging tell you is going on?

Comment: So I debugged by putting all the legal destination squares of any piece of opposite color (any piece that might be able to check the king of the player in question).  Then I looped through and the white queen's legal squares arrayList *does* contain the black king square.  Maybe arrayList's .contains() method works differently from how I expect?

Comment: contains() returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). Check if blackKingSquare do equals the one in the arrayList. Maybe you need to override equals(), or don't use contains() and instead write another method to check it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrongly put ! in

```
//if piece at current square is opposite color of candidate player
if (! myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getColor().equals(oppositeColor)) {
```

so you actually check pieces that have the candidate's color.
Change it to :

```
if (myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getColor().equals(oppositeColor)) {
```

Comment: Ah, so that was definitely an issue.  Fixed that (as you suggested) tho the issue persists...